# Bootstrap empty div placeholder

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap project and i want to give a message if a div is empty. I have a panel-heading and a panel-body, and if there are no nodes in the panel-body i want a message like "something will be added here".

What could be a good way to go? I can use CSS or Javascript.

Child nodes of the panel-body can be added and deleted, so it can get empty again. Checking this in javascript all the time doens't sound good to me, so it would have to be a listener to the emptying of the div, is that possible?

A good CSS solution would be better.

Comment: using js is the fastest and simplest, and most suitable solution here. P.S. @Kevin - does it matter?

Comment: If you want to conditionally evaluate on the client side, you'll need javascript. If you control the population of the Div via the number of rows in a database, for example, you could use your server-side scripting language to conditionally echo your Div and your view would be redrawn per request.

Comment: I just found i can use the CSS :empty selector. But it's only IE9+

Answer (score 0):

With some CSS trickery, you can show a message when an element contains no children.

### [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m8qLf/)

```
ul {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul:before {
    content: 'No Results Found.';
    height: 50px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2em;
}

ul li {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```